# how to get the label associated with an android account?

Tags: android, account

I want to get the displayed name, id the label, that is associated with a android account.

For instance, when you create a new contact, you have to precise the type of the account and to do so, you can pick up one of the account that enable contact synchronisation, or the 'telephone' type.

I have search thru the AccountManager, ContactsContract.Settings and SyncAdapterType but cannot find this label.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

seems that the following classes answer my question:

AccountManager
AuthenticatorDescription

I (finally) found them in the ContactManager sample from android sample.

But the real answer is to get the label thru the PackageManager. This is explain in the sample.

Comment: Very confusing answer . You dint you accept your own answer , if it is working for you .